# This simple UPDATE query wont work

Tags: php, mysql, set

This update code always worked perfectly but suddently it doesnt work anymore..

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE members SET username='$username', password='$password', email='$email', wage='$wage', rights='$rights' WHERE id='$id'");
```

While this works:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE members SET username='$username' WHERE id='$id'");
```

In the same situation..

What do I do wrong? Used this before in my script and thats working perfectly. 
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @Glavić, that's relevant and the OP should read it, but it's not a duplicate of this question.

Comment: Does it throw an error? Do those columns exist in your table? What is the content of those variables?

Comment: What are the variables? Make sure that they have something in them and aren't breaking the SQL by having a special character in them.

Comment: Columns exist and no error, it just doesnt update..

Comment: @BeatAlex Do you think '@' could cause this? The email contains a @

Comment: That should be ok, I'm talking about any `"`, `'`, `)`, `;` or the like.

Comment: @user2911924: how do you check if there is an mysql error?

Comment: Look at dikirill's answer. I think he has the solution.

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE members SET username='$username', password='$password', email='$email', wage='$wage', rights='$rights' WHERE id='$id'") or die (mysqli_error($con));       <--- or die mysqli_error provides for error message

Comment: Could it be that @BeatAlex is right? Show us example of data you are trying to submit? It could be that nothing is changed, and mysql ignores update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `members` SET `username`='$username', `password`='$password', `email`='$email', `wage`='$wage', `rights`='$rights' WHERE `id`='$id'");
```

Comment: `PASSWORD` is **not** reserved word! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Worked, odd how I didnt had to use this in the past but suddently it doesnt work without it.. Thanks!